# Client side validation doesn't work in ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a login page which has a following model:

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public LoginFormViewModel Form { get; set; }
}
public class LoginFormViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the page html:

```
@model SocialNetwork.Web.ViewModels.LoginViewModel

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
}

<h2>Login</h2>

<style>
    #btn-login {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 14px;
    }

    #checkbox-remember-me {
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
</style>

<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Login">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label asp-for="Form.UserName"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Form.UserName" name="UserName" class="form-control">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Form.UserName"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label asp-for="Form.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Form.Password" name="Password" class="form-control">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Form.Password"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="checkbox pull-right" id="checkbox-remember-me">
                <label>
                    <input asp-for="Form.RememberMe" name="RememberMe">
                    Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn btn-primary">
                Log In
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And client side validation simply doesn't work, those `<span asp-validation-for="some-property"></span>` simply don't work; but `<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>` does, when page refreshes, ofcourse.

I haven't changed almost anything in my _Layout.cshtml. I am sure that those scripts at the top of Login.cshtml are in that folder, and that they are being included.

The forms action in the controller takes LoginFormViewModel as it's parameter and it's all ok with it.

I have overriden the name because, otherwise, form wasn't being bound to it's model on form submition. The name of Model.Form.Password was Form_Password, and it couldn't map that into the model on submition, because in model it was called just Password.
So, I guess that must be a problem, so there must be a another way to map that form to its model on submission, right?

Comment: Because you go and override the `name` attributes using `name="..."` NEVER under any circumstance attempt to change the `name` attributes when using TagHelpers

Comment: Why do you use a 2-step design with that `Form` property?  It seems pointless and you do invite problems with all sorts of mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are getting the Form.Property but this is the way it should work

but the model should look like

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
{    
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

And the associated html

```
<form asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
            <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UseName"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

The asp- tag helpers use the properties of the model you are using in the view..

Comment: it wouldn't work because properties Email and Pasword are not in the root of the model, but in it's Form property.

Comment: Edited...didn't notice the model at the top of the OP

Comment: but i don't wanna do it that way, I want the form to be nested in the model

Comment: @Scarass...why, what is the possible benefit of that? You are breaking the KISS idiom.

Comment: Because it belongs in the nested property named Form, because its' not data for the whole page, but just for the form. Controller action should take just that form, not the whole view model.

Comment: @Scarass...See@Henks comment above...what other "data" do you need for a login page

Comment: it doesn't matter :), there can be other data that doesn't have to do with the login form

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); //in Configure() method of StartUp.cs class
```